# FutureBuilder and ListView.builder

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone please explain to me how to use itemCount from ListView.Builder which is inside of an FutureBuilder.

For now my FirebaseCloud Store only has one Document , and my app is returning an infinity list of documents,

I tried to use `itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,` 

however, Get the error: `Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'documents'. Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot' Tried calling: documents`

**EDIT** it should only show this document one time and one of a kind if there is more than one document related to the UID

[image]

Here is my Code

`````
final tabs = [
        Center(

            child: (Scaffold(
                body: FutureBuilder(
                    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('users')
                        .doc(uid)
                        .get(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.data == null)
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      DocumentSnapshot manuais = snapshot.data;

                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        print('okkk');
                        print(manuais.data()['nome']);
                      } else {
                        print('nopeeeee');
                      }
                      return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: ListView.builder(

                            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,

                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {


                              DocumentSnapshot manuais = snapshot.data;

                              return Card(
                                color: Colors.grey[250],
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      new Image.asset(
                                        'Images/pdflogo.png',
                                        width: 32,
                                      ),
                                      Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          (manuais.data()['nome'].toString()),
                                          maxLines: 1,
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      ButtonBar(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          FlatButton(
                                              child: const Text(
                                                  'Compartilhar / Download'),
                                              onPressed: () async {
                                                var request = await HttpClient()
                                                    .getUrl(Uri.parse(manuais
                                                        .data()['documento']));
                                                var response =
                                                    await request.close();
                                                Uint8List bytes =
                                                    await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(
                                                        response);
                                                await Share.file(
                                                    'ESYS AMLOG',
                                                    'Manual.pdf',
                                                    bytes,
                                                    'image/jpg');
                                              }),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                      );
                    })))),

````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do:

```
itemCount : 1
```

Since you are only retrieving one document, when you do:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('users')
                        .doc(uid)
                        .get()
```

The above will always retrieve one document since the document id will always be unique.

Comment: Wow that worked, but how I show another document of this collection , in the list?

Comment: you need to do `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").get()` and then in `itemCount` do `snapshot.data.docs.length`

Comment: However, on firebase cloud store db , i cant add 2 documents with the same UID

Comment: Same uid as field but not same uid as document id

Answer (score 1):

You need to get length like this.

```
itemCount: snapshot.data.data().length,
```

Comment: then i get :  Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'length'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: length

Comment: Can you try `snapshot.data.data().length` ?

Comment: I did: snapshot.data.data().length;    ,  im not getting error however my list still infinity

Comment: my bad i got a error:```` Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: call()```` when i changed to itemCount: snapshot.data().length;

Comment: What do you mean "_my list still infinity_" ?

Comment: on my firebase cloud store i just have onde document related to this UID.
my app is showing the same document many times in the list , it should only show one of a kind i will edit one print screen here hold on

Answer (score 0):

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        print('okkk');
                        print(manuais.data()['nome']);
return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: ListView.builder(

                            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,

                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {


                              DocumentSnapshot manuais = snapshot.data;

                              return Card(
                                color: Colors.grey[250],
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      new Image.asset(
                                        'Images/pdflogo.png',
                                        width: 32,
                                      ),
                                      Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          (manuais.data()['nome'].toString()),
                                          maxLines: 1,
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      ButtonBar(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          FlatButton(
                                              child: const Text(
                                                  'Compartilhar / Download'),
                                              onPressed: () async {
                                                var request = await HttpClient()
                                                    .getUrl(Uri.parse(manuais
                                                        .data()['documento']));
                                                var response =
                                                    await request.close();
                                                Uint8List bytes =
                                                    await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(
                                                        response);
                                      await Share.file(
                                             'ESYS AMLOG',
                                           'Manual.pdf',
                                               bytes,
                                            'image/jpg') ...(all your brackets go here)
    
         }
```

Comment: try return in the if condition in which snapshot.hasData

Comment: I dont get it , what the if condition that i sue to test if the data is passing has related to the problem?